# Python pandas "filter" a time series for trading days only

Tags: python, pandas, trading

I have a two datasets that look like this:

[image]

What I'd like to do is filter out non-trading days on the "data" dataframe. I assume it would be comparing the data.index.date of each row to the data.index.date of trading_days, then returning the row if there's a match. If there is no match, then it is not a trading day and the row is not returned. This effectively filters out the dataset of non-trading days.

However, going row-by-row here to check if the two data.index.dates are equal using an apply() function to return the row seems inefficient - I feel like there's a more efficient way to do this since I will do this on a 180M row dataframe.

Is there some kind of "merge" or "join" like:

```
data.join(trading_days)
```

that will filter for only the dates where date.index.date matches? I need to have it all by the minute-level (as shown in the "data" dataframe) but simply filter out non-trade dates. Thanks for your help!

UPDATE to include values (please let me know if there's a better way to paste these):

```
In[5]: data.head(30).values
Out[6]: 
array([[ 438.9,  438.9,  438.9,  438.9,    0. ],
       [ 438.9,  438.9,  438.7,  438.7,   31. ],
       [ 438.6,  438.6,  438.6,  438.6,    7. ],
       [ 438.4,  438.7,  438.4,  438.4,    4. ],
       [ 438.4,  438.4,  438.3,  438.3,    4. ],
       [ 438.2,  438.2,  438.2,  438.2,    1. ],
       [ 438.2,  438.2,  438.2,  438.2,    0. ],
       [ 438.2,  438.2,  438.2,  438.2,    1. ],
       [ 438.2,  438.2,  438.2,  438.2,    0. ],
       [ 438.1,  438.1,  438.1,  438.1,    3. ],
       [ 438. ,  438. ,  437.9,  438. ,    6. ],
       [ 438. ,  438.2,  438. ,  438. ,    8. ],
       [ 438.2,  438.2,  438.1,  438.1,    6. ],
       [ 438.1,  438.1,  438.1,  438.1,    4. ],
       [ 438.1,  438.1,  438.1,  438.1,    0. ],
       [ 438.3,  438.3,  438.3,  438.3,    1. ],
       [ 438.3,  438.3,  438.3,  438.3,    0. ],
       [ 438.3,  438.3,  438.3,  438.3,    0. ],
       [ 438.1,  438.1,  438.1,  438.1,    1. ],
       [ 438. ,  438. ,  437.9,  437.9,   54. ],
       [ 437.8,  437.8,  437.8,  437.8,   10. ],
       [ 437.8,  437.8,  437.8,  437.8,    1. ],
       [ 437.8,  437.8,  437.8,  437.8,    6. ],
       [ 437.8,  437.8,  437.8,  437.8,    0. ],
       [ 437.9,  438. ,  437.9,  438. ,   12. ],
       [ 437.9,  438. ,  437.9,  438. ,    0. ],
       [ 437.9,  438. ,  437.9,  438. ,    0. ],
       [ 437.9,  438. ,  437.9,  438. ,    0. ],
       [ 437.9,  437.9,  437.9,  437.9,    1. ],
       [ 437.9,  437.9,  437.8,  437.8,    4. ]])
```

And here are the time stamps:

```
In[10]: data.head(30).index.values
Out[11]: 
array(['2005-01-02T13:59:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:00:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:01:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:02:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:03:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:04:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:05:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:06:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:07:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:08:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:09:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:10:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:11:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:12:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:13:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:14:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:15:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:16:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:17:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:18:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:19:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:20:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:21:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:22:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:23:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:24:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:25:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:26:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:27:00.000000000-0500',
       '2005-01-02T14:28:00.000000000-0500'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

And the trading_days is a read.csv from here: http://pastebin.com/5N01Gi5V

SECOND UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: Can you post some sample data as plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a join the following way:

1. Add a `days` column to `data` which contains the day of the index.
2. `pd.merge(days, data, on='days')`

This does an inner join by default, so only the rows from `data` with days which appear in the `days` frame will be in the result.

Comment: For both answers, I did:

`data['days'] = data.index.date`
`df = pd.merge(trading_days, data, on='days')`
`# df = data.merge(trading_days, how='inner', left_on='days', right_index=True)`
`df.count()`

And I get an empty dataframe.. this is probably a stupid mistake but I'm not sure I understand why the merge on 'days' would return nothing.

Comment: Check the types of the 'days' column in the two dataframes. `data.index.date` will return `datetime` objects.

Comment: Ah I see now. Ok I was able to merge but now I see all my minute data is missing from the index (as it was there in the original "data" dataframe).. any ideas on how to merge but retain this index?

Comment: I got it by using `df = pd.merge(trading_days, data, on='days', left_index=True)` to retain the index

Thanks for all your help (and Bob's too)!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  I would create another column in the data dataframe that contained the datetime value in your index, but with a format that was similar to one used in your trading_days dataframe.  So 2005-01-02 23:59:00*00:00 becomes 2005-01-02

Then you could use Merge http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

```
data.merge (trading_days, how='inner', left_on='newcolumn', right_index=True)
```